# Embed pdb into assembly

Tags: .net, deployment, pdb-files

I want my application to be distributable as a *single .exe file* but I want to be able to get nice error reports with source code line numbers (the application simply sends email with `exception.ToString()` and some additional information when unhandled exception occurs).

Is there any way to embed .pdb into assembly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use MiniDumps instead of "exception.ToString()". It will give you a lot more information and does not need the .pdb to be distributed with the .exe.

Useful Link: [Post-Mortem Debugging Your Application with Minidumps and Visual Studio .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx)

Comment: Absolutely, however you need to keep the PDBs of every build you ship for that to work reliably - best to setup a symbol server internally (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680693(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Can I make minidump of a running application? For example, if I get unhandled exception in WinForms, I will display error dialog to the user with an option to send error report and **continue** working with application (in contrast to terminating application).

Answer (score 5):

I have used the following `AssemblyResolve` handler and then embedding both `dll` and `pdb` of any assemblies. You could set this up as anything that runs first thing in the application before dependencies are needed.

```
    private static void SetupEmbeddedAssemblyResolve()
    {
        // Based on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var name = args.Name;
            var asmName = new AssemblyName(name);

            // Any retargetable assembly should be resolved directly using normal load e.g. System.Core issue: 
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793959/filenotfoundexception-when-trying-to-load-autofac-as-an-embedded-assembly
            if (name.EndsWith("Retargetable=Yes"))
            {
                return Assembly.Load(asmName);
            }

            var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var resourceNames = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

            var resourceToFind = asmName.Name + ".dll";
            var resourceName = resourceNames.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Contains(resourceToFind));

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceName)) { return null; }

            var symbolsToFind = asmName.Name + ".pdb";
            var symbolsName = resourceNames.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Contains(symbolsToFind));

            var assemblyData = LoadResourceBytes(executingAssembly, resourceName);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(symbolsName))
            { 
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Loading '{0}' as embedded resource '{1}'", resourceToFind, resourceName));

                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
            else
            {
                var symbolsData = LoadResourceBytes(executingAssembly, symbolsName);

                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Loading '{0}' as embedded resource '{1}' with symbols '{2}'", resourceToFind, resourceName, symbolsName));

                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData, symbolsData);
            }
        };
    }

    private static byte[] LoadResourceBytes(Assembly executingAssembly, string resourceName)
    {
        using (var stream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            var assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];

            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);

            return assemblyData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have made a short blog post with this as well at: http://www.codingmurmur.com/2014/02/embedded-assembly-loading-with-support.html

Comment: Woah. I knew you could do it with dll files, but this works with pdb files too? Neat. This does mean that, to use this to make a project into a single-file distribution, you'd need to put your main application into an external dll project, though.

Comment: Well only if you don't want the main application pdb to be next to the exe. We can live with that.

Comment: I did say a _a single-file_ distribution ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could write a stub executable, that contains as embedded resources, both your actual executable and its pdb file. Upon starting the staub executable, it extracts the real executable and the pdb into a temporary directory and launches it.

Just like some Installers or other applications do.

I'm not sure if it is worth the extra effort though.

Comment: I also had this idea. This will also let me to apply compression to my binaries and make .exe smaller. The drawback is longer start up time. I just hope there's a simpler way of doing this.