# FileNotFoundException when trying to load Autofac as an embedded assembly

Tags: c#, dll, embedded-resource

Previous versions of Autofac worked, but since they switched to making it a Portable Class Library it won't load.

I tried applying the fix listed [here](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) (KB2468871) but it told me that it was not needed.

The error goes away when I move the Autofac.dll file into the same location as the executable.  When it loads it from the external DLL it loads fine.

Why won't it work as an embedded DLL?

Here is the exception:

```
        System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

        Stack trace: 
           at Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration..ctor(Guid id, IInstanceActivator activator, IComponentLifetime lifetime, InstanceSharing sharing, InstanceOwnership ownership, IEnumerable`1 services, IDictionary`2 metadata)
           at Autofac.Core.Container..ctor()
           at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions options)
           at MyApp.Configuration.Bootstrapper.Run(String[] args) in c:\Dev\MyApp\App\Configuration\Bootstrapper.cs:line 25
           at MyApp.Configuration.EntryPoint.Main(String[] args) in c:\Dev\MyApp\App\Configuration\EntryPoint.cs:line 22
```

If it helps, here is the part of the .csproj file that embeds the DLLs into the executable:

```
  <Target Name="AfterResolveReferences">
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)' == '.dll'">
    <LogicalName>%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory)%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Filename)%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)</LogicalName>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

... and here is the EntryPoint class:

```
internal static class EntryPoint
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) => loadEmbeddedAssembly(e.Name);
        Bootstrapper.Run(args); // must call separate class when using embedded assemblies
    }

    private static Assembly loadEmbeddedAssembly(string name)
    {
        var container = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var path = new AssemblyName(name).Name + ".dll";

        using (var stream = container.GetManifestResourceStream(path))
        {
            if (stream == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your assembly resolve handler isn't being run.  Can you confirm this?  Also, it's so much easier to just use the designer to add the file as a resource. You can access it via a byte[] property [root namespace].Properties.Resources.SomeEmbeddedFile.  Slam it in a MemoryStream and be done with it.  GMRS is old school.

Comment: @Will if the assembly resolve handler isn't being run, it wouldn't be able to load Autofac at all.  Autofac is getting loaded, it's just having trying to load an old version of System.Core.It seems as though the Retargetable property of the assembly isn't working when it's loaded as an embedded resource.  It does work when I copy the Autofac dll into the same folder as the exe.

Comment: Oh, gotcha.  Probably something to do with load contexts. They're damned hard to understand and they aren't documented well at all.  Tried loading it yourself?

Comment: Looks similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18277499/644812). In the comments, leppie recommends using `LoadFrom` which seemed to work for the asker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could easily repro your problem by using Assembly.Load(byte[]) on a PCL library that targeted Silverlight and used a System.Core type, this problem isn't specific to Autofac.  It is a rather evil way to load an assembly, about as bad as Assembly.LoadFile().  Not having a loading context is a recipe for DLL Hell.

The CLR has an unenviable job to do with these PCL library references, it needs to magically map the retargetable assembly references to a real one.  In other words, the 2.0.5.0 reference needs to be mapped to the correct one for the runtime version, 4.0.0.0 in your case.  It can only do this if it has a good idea what the actual runtime version is, not having a loading context makes that difficult.  Clearly it doesn't attempt to do so, it fires the AssemblyResolve event again for the 2.0.5.0 reference.

Which is the solution, remarkable simple in hind-sight.  Just intercept the resolve request for the retargetable assembly references and use Assembly.Load() to let the CLR sort it out from the loading context of your AppDomain.  Alter your AssemblyResolve event handler like this:

```
private static Assembly loadEmbeddedAssembly(string name)
{
    if (name.EndsWith("Retargetable=Yes")) {
        return Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(name));
    }
    // Rest of your code
    //...
}
```

This worked well in my test app, I trust it will solve your problem with Autofac as well.

Comment: Great that helped me a lot to get a decent AssemblyResolve handler up and running with pdb-file support see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518073/embed-pdb-into-assembly/21850462#21850462

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is how you try to load your EmbeddedAssembly.

I have very small knowledge about how you can do it 
but i know the following example from code project works fine for me so maybe it will help you :-)

[Load DLL From Embedded Resource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource)

*(If i misunderstand your question please tell me and i will delete my Answer)*