# VS2015 C# interactive: error CS7069: Reference to type 'Object' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, read-eval-print-loop, c#-interactive

I just updated to [VS2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx), and started playing around with the [C# interactive window](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2015/103). I wanted to use a static method in a static class in one of my .NET 4.0 targeted library projects, so I right-clicked on the project in Solution Explorer, and selected `Initialize Interactive with Project`. The output in the interactive window looks like this (I replaced some of the full paths with '..' for brevity):

```
#reset
Resetting execution engine.
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
#r "..\src\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll"
#r "..\src\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"
#r "..\src\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll"
#r "..\src\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.8\lib\net40\System.IO.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Net.dll"
#r "..\src\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.8\lib\net40\System.Runtime.dll"
#r "..\src\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.8\lib\net40\System.Threading.Tasks.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll"
#r "MyDll.dll"
using MyDll;
(1,7): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Object' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
```

Note the nasty little line at the end, blocking my path to happiness:

**(1,7): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Object' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found**

I get intellisense for the classes in the project, but I get the same error any time I try to run a statement. I can still run simple things like:

```
> string.Format("No one knows my {0}", "suffering")
"No one knows my suffering"
>
```

Anyone have any ideas about why this is happening or how to fix it? I'll update this question with any [un]successful suggested fixes.

Comment: Looks [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19636730/17034), you do need to document your type of project of course.  Use connect.microsoft.com if you think it needs to work.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not exactly sure how to map that answer to this question, but I tried execute `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(...)` from the interactive window. I'm getting red squigglies under `System` anywhere I type it, even trying a using statement `using System.Reflection;` - is that useful at all?

Comment: Does it work on the command-line interface (`csi`)?

Comment: @PauloMorgado which part do you mean? Is the 'command-line interface' something different from the interactive window I'm describing? I don't know of another window to use this feature.

Comment: It's always clean. You don't `#reset` it.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I didn't enter `#reset` myself. That happens when I select `Initialize Interactive with Project` from the context menu of the project in Solution Explorer.

Comment: @HansPassant please take a look at my answer below - if you're interested, I'd love to get your take on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What ultimately fixed it for me was entering this ***right in the*** [C# Interactive window](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2015/103).:

`#r "System.Runtime"`

If there's anyone that can provide a thorough background explanation as to why this worked, I'd love to give you the accepted answer. I just got lucky.

Comment: Where do you enter that?!

Comment: @JotaPardo Right in the [C# Interactive Window](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2015/103)

Answer (score 3):

While it might seem a little late to add an answer, it's actually still a possible current issue with **Visual Studio 2019 (v16.9.4)**, or at least it was for me...

In my case it was not related to a reference to a .NET Framework standard package but with a reference to one of my projects in the solution.

I successfully solved the issue by following these steps:

1. Remove the package/project reference from the project where the issue resides.
2. Clean the issued project (*for more cleanup, you can also delete the bin/obj folders from Explorer*).
3. *If the reference is to a project, `Clean` and `Rebuild` the referenced project.*
4. Add again the reference to the package/project and rebuild all in the solution.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had an incompatible package referenced, which caused this error. Overlooked during package upgrade. Removed the reference & fixing namespaces did the trick.