# Connect Xamarin Cross-Platform project to OData Service

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, shared-project, simple.odata

I am using Visual studio 2017 Xamarin Cross-Platform template. This should connect to an OData. So I added these NuGet Packages:

```
Microsoft.data.odata (v 5.8.2)
Microsoft.odata.Client (v 6.16.0)
```

There is no error yet. But:

According to [xamarin documentations](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/Simple.OData.Client/true) I should add `Simple.OData.Client`. Just after adding `Simple.OData.Client (v 4.26.0)` I am getting `Reference to type 'Object' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found` with code `CS7069` in almost all types in shared project.

I did some googling and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36723359/256431). I don't know where to add that.

I added `System.Runtime` but that didn't do anything.

> Please consider the solution as not-changed-xamarin-cross-platform solution with 3 projects. `SharedProject` , `Android` and `iOS`

Is there a version mismatch? If so, what versions of these refrences are compatible with each other?

Thanks in advance :)