# CS7069 C# Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlconnection

I am building winForm application,
and i try to make a connection function for mssql Server
but SqlConnection open/close always show
"CS7069  C# Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found"
how could I fix this issue?

```
 public class SQLAPI
{
    SqlConnection cn;

    Boolean openConnect()
    {
        bool rtn = false;
        try
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=testDB;UID=ad;PWD=1234");
            cn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }        
        return rtn;
    }

    void closeConnect()
    {
        try {
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are the database credentials Windows.  If so do not use UID and PWD..  Instead use Trusted_Connection=True; (see https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).  also open up SQL Server Management Studio and get the instead of the data base which is in the login window.  You need localhost/{instance}

Comment: cn.Open/ cn.Close show the message before compile....

Comment: The error is : ERROR_TS_INCOMPATIBLE_SESSIONS, The target session is incompatible with the current session (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--6000-8199-).  I don't thing your project (and reference projects) go completely recompiled due to dependencies in the compiler.  I would make a copy of the project bin folder and then delete to force all the code to get recompiled.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723359/vs2015-c-sharp-interactive-error-cs7069-reference-to-type-object-claims-it-i