# Powershell Core "Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0"

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to develop a PowerShell Core module that depends on a helper library written with .NET Standard 2 in mind.

My helper library works fine according to my tests, and it does what it should.

For testing the module I compile it and copy the necessary file to a Docker image containing Nano Server (which has PowerShell Core installed by default), and with dotnet core installed through one of Microsofts own install scripts.

Importing the module goes along fine, but when I try to run the module I receive:

> Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0.

For the PowerShell module I'm using: PowerShellStandard.Library 3.0.0-preview-01 and WindowsAzure.Storage 8.6.0 (which my helper library also depends on). The helper library is compiled against target framework netstandard2.0.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here to get it to work? Any pointers or help would be appriciated.

Comment: See "[*'Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, …'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45021965/1364007)" - may be relevant. A comment says: "*Never, never load a reference assembly, they are only suitable to build your program. This went wrong because you wrote the AssemblyResolve event handler, should work just fine without it. The key is to let the CLR figure out the real runtime assembly that contains the type, good odds that this workaround works on .NETCore as well.*"

Comment: I'm going to check that out then. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, ...'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021965/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-netstandard-version-2-0-0-0-reference)