# Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, server

I am Getting this error when I upload my asp.net website on hostgator server but when i upload it on other server like somme.com my site works perfectly I dont what is happening

Error: **Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

[image: Error 1]

to remove this error i add these lines in my web.config file under the system.web section

```
<compilation debug="False" targetFramework="4.5.2" >
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
            PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"/>
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
```

After add these lines i get the new error

Configuration Error

Parser Error Message: **Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

[image: Error 2]

please tell how to solve these error thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, ...'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021965/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-netstandard-version-2-0-0-0-reference)

Comment: yeah but how i will pass the reference on the server?